# UWP Sqlite db encryption

Tags: windows, uwp, winrt-xaml

I'm developing an enterprise UWP application. I'm using sqlite db to store the customer data. It gets stored in the sandboxed folder. But any user can navigate to that folder and access the db and get the data. I'm feeling this as an security issue. So I trying encrypting the data, but the retrival of data is very slow. Can anyone please suggest me if this is safe approach or is there anyother better approach than this.

Comment: Encrypting the data doesn't really help much since the key will be embedded in the app so someone can just extract it and decrypt anyway. What is the data and why do you feel it needs to be encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application folder is a restricted folder, If the user want to access it through the file explorer, the user needs to access it as an administrator and have elevated permissions. This is the system's protection for UWP application folders.

If you need simple encryption, you can consider encrypting the data stored in the database (such as using Base64 encryption when writing a field, and using Base64 decryption when reading it).

Generally speaking, the data stored using Sqlite should not be sensitive data. If you have doubts about data security, please consider other data access solutions.

For example, hosting the database on the server allows the client to indirectly access the data in the database through API.

Comment: If the db data is encrypted how can we perform record search

Comment: Note the user does not need to be an administrator to read or write their own data.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. If the user wants to manually open the application folder (`WindowsApps`) through the file explorer, this needs to be elevated.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Encrypted data in the data table is only preliminary encryption. The encrypted data is sensitive data, such as passwords or user information. But if it is a key value (such as a user ID), there is no need for encryption. If you need to perform keyword fuzzy queries, this internal data encryption method is not suitable, please consider hosting the database on the server.